# \captionof options: bold name for figure

Tags: floats, captions, positioning

I am using the `capt-of` package for my figures to avoid floating.

I fix the figures in the position I want by using:

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{figure1.png}
\captionof{figure}{bla bla}\label{fig1}
\end{center}
```

I obtain something like: `Figure 1: bla bla.` Anyhow, I am wondering if I can change the style of the caption, from `Figure 1:` to `\textbf{Figure 1.}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `caption` package which provides the same macro.

[image: caption format]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \captionof{figure}{bla bla}\label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```